# i'm having problem with retrieving the data from MYSQL to compute it to netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans

[i'm trying to proof that my database can retrieve my data so I can use it as variable. but everytime I run it on netbeans it says that "java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION:Column'SELECT result, COUNT(result) AS 'result_w' FROM coach_team_data WHERE result=\"W\" GROUP BY result' not found"][1]

```
String result_w=rs.getString(" SELECT result, COUNT(result) AS 'result_w' FROM coach_team_data WHERE result=\"W\" GROUP BY result");   
d.setText(result_w);
```

Comment: Can you add the table description (DESCRIBE TABLE coach_team_data) to your question?

Comment: From the error message, `rs.getString` is expecting a column name, not a query.